# RTextTools error in create_matrix

Tags: r

Hi I'm really new to programming in R and RTextTools one the following [A Supervised Learning Package for Text Classification](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/collingwood-jurka-boydstun-etal.pdf) when try to run this code

```
# CREATE THE DOCUMENT-TERM MATRIX
doc_matrix <- create_matrix(USCongress$text,
                        language="english", removeNumbers=TRUE,
                        stemWords=TRUE, removeSparseTerms=.998)`
```

I get this error

> Error in as.matrix(textColumns) : object 'USCongress' not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing package `maxent` which is a sample dataset containing labeled bills from the United State Congress.

```
install.packages("maxent")
library(maxent)
# Import data
USCongress <- read.csv(system.file("data/USCongress.csv.gz",package="maxent"))
doc_matrix <- create_matrix(USCongress$text, language="english", removeNumbers=TRUE,
                            stemWords=TRUE, removeSparseTerms=.998)

And output:

<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 4449, terms: 904)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 49528/3972368
Sparsity           : 99%
Maximal term length: 14
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

Comment: Thanks,  Miha but still I get anther error Error
 in simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v), nrow = length(allTerms),  : 
  'i, j, v' different lengths
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mclapply(unname(content(x)), termFreq, control) :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
2: In simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v), nrow = length(allTerms),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: And from where i can get the USCongress.csv file

Comment: Did you try the code I've posted:`USCongress <- read.csv(system.file("data/USCongress.csv.gz",package="maxent"))` because here should be data set.

Comment: Yes this is the code 
"
library(maxent)
library(RTextTools)
library(tm) 
# Import data
USCongress <- read.csv(system.file("data/USCongress.csv.gz",package="maxent"))
doc_matrix <- create_matrix(USCongress$text, language="english", removeNumbers=TRUE,
                            stemWords=TRUE, removeSparseTerms=.998)

Comment: So you should have USCongress.csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue on setmWords=TRUE, I made a change to FALSE and the and code work 
`

```
library(maxent)
library(RTextTools)
library(tm) 
# Import data
data(USCongress)
doc_matrix <- create_matrix(USCongress$text, language="english", removeNumbers=TRUE,
                            stemWords=FALSE, removeSparseTerms=.998)
container <- create_container(doc_matrix, USCongress$major, trainSize=1:4000,
                              testSize=4001:4449, virgin=FALSE)
SVM <- train_model(container,"SVM")
GLMNET <- train_model(container,"GLMNET")
MAXENT <- train_model(container,"MAXENT")
SLDA <- train_model(container,"SLDA")
BOOSTING <- train_model(container,"BOOSTING")
BAGGING <- train_model(container,"BAGGING")
RF <- train_model(container,"RF")
NNET <- train_model(container,"NNET")
TREE <- train_model(container,"TREE")


SVM_CLASSIFY <- classify_model(container, SVM)
GLMNET_CLASSIFY <- classify_model(container, GLMNET)
MAXENT_CLASSIFY <- classify_model(container, MAXENT)
SLDA_CLASSIFY <- classify_model(container, SLDA)
BOOSTING_CLASSIFY <- classify_model(container, BOOSTING)
BAGGING_CLASSIFY <- classify_model(container, BAGGING)
RF_CLASSIFY <- classify_model(container, RF)
NNET_CLASSIFY <- classify_model(container, NNET)
TREE_CLASSIFY <- classify_model(container, TREE)


analytics <- create_analytics(container,
                              cbind(SVM_CLASSIFY, SLDA_CLASSIFY,
                                    BOOSTING_CLASSIFY, BAGGING_CLASSIFY,
                                    RF_CLASSIFY, GLMNET_CLASSIFY,
                                    NNET_CLASSIFY, TREE_CLASSIFY,
                                    MAXENT_CLASSIFY))
topic_summary <- analytics@label_summary
SVM <- cross_validate(container, 4, "SVM")
```

`
Know I went to use Arabic language any suggestion